# By how much did the content of the Airbus A320 FCOM expand over the last 40 years?

Tags: aviation-history, airbus-a320, airbus

The Airbus A320 has been in service for almost 40 years now. I imagine that the current manuals are much larger than the manuals provided in the 80s, mainly for three reasons:

- The newer models feature many more systems (EGPWS, Auto TCAS, ROPS, BUSS, ...)
- The manuals were amended and refined based on accidents, incidents and shared experiences
- The manuals are subject to "content creep", where both structure and content bloat up over time, as many people worked on the documents for many generations, but "old stuff" is never removed.

I would consider 1+2 healthy and 3 unhealthy. Does anyone have access to the original docs from the 80s / 90s for comparison?